# Android Activity/Intent vs. Qt Signal/Slot vs. iPhone ?/?

Tags: iphone, android, qt, android-intent, signals-slots

I'm trying to investigate similarities of *communication between objects/components* on different mobile platforms.

On Android, there is the *Activity/Intent* concept to pass information along, on Qt we have *signals and slots*.

Questions that arise here:

1. **is it legitimate to compare Activity/Intent to signal/slot concept?** The foremost difference from my point of view is the different granularity level. While Activities/Intents operate on "whole screens" (Activities to be more precise, since an Activity doesn't necessarily represent a separate screen), Signals/Slots are defined for smaller objects, such as Widgets (in fact, for every class that is derived from QObject).
2. Having platform-independence in mind, would you say the *concepts are fundamentally too different*, or could a developer overcome the technical differences in terms of object communication and "abstract" the application logic sufficiently to minimize porting efforts? how?
3. **is there a comparable concept on iOS?** (e.g. Target-Action mechanism - or more like Delegates or Notifications provided by ObjectiveC).

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak for the difference between android's intent and iOS - have never done anything in QT, but here we go:
Intents are (at least to my knowledge) mostly used to signal changing state of the phone or to change the life-cycle-state of different objects. They are not commonly used for finer granularity stuff like notification of changed vales and such.
In iOS, the Notification System exists for both fine-granular and coarse-grained information (aka. system state and even model changes) - but it functions quite differently.

I don't see any direct similarity between both of these mechanisms. With Androids Intents I can start new Activites and maybe pass some values to another Activity if I really have to. With iOS Notifications I can pass any kind of values from A to B, but would have to implement my own logic to for example start a service on a specific Notification. Also, the Notification Management in iOS is much more explict than the Android Intents.

Answer (score 1):

1. Qt's Signal-and-slot can not be compared to Android's intent. Signal and slot applies to everything in Qt; it comes from QObject class which is the superclass of all Qt objects, hence the central concept of Qt. On the other hand, Android uses several mechanisms for object communication. It uses intents for activities and services, but it also uses callbacks for event handling. They also offer different levels of flexibility: you may feed as many arguments to signals and slots, you may attach some data on intents, but you can only pass a view object to android callbacks.
2. It's fundamentally different since Android doesn't only use intents as explained above.
3. can't answer that as I'm no iOS programmer.

Answer (score 0):

For a comparison of Notifications on iOS vs. Intents on Android, I came up w/ following summary:

Commonalities:

- Both mechanisms can be used to register for any notifications that report system changes your application needs (e.g., the battery level changes)
- both types can trigger lifecycle state changes

Differences:

- Granularity level

  - Intents are used to pass information between Activities, Services or Broadcast receivers
  - Notifications can be used to pass information between any kind of objects, be it either fine-granular to notify sbdy when a single GUI element changes, or coarse-granular to react when certain system events arrive
- IPC

  - Intents can be used for inter-application communication (implicit Intents, no specific receiving component mentioned, late-binding), as well as intra-app communication (explicit Intents, receiving component specified, early-binding)
  - Notifications are limited to intra-application communication on iOS (is there another way of achieving this?)
- Use Case:

  - Intents are usually used to start other Activities (e.g., display another screen) or start some Services (e.g., play a music in background).
  - on iOS, one would have to implement one's own logic to transition to another screen or start playing some music in background.

In the end, what my question comes down to, was: **as these concepts seem to be fundamentally different, is this a true obstacle for designing platform-independent Android-/iOS-Apps?**
*Or do you have suggestions on how to "abstract" those mechanisms, and minimize porting efforts?* (cross-platform solutions also must have means to translate these concepts into native code behind the scenes?)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've looked at Qt, but my recollection is that signals/slots looked an awful lot like Objective-C (iOS) selectors (especially for IBAction methods). Typical use

```
[button addTarget: controller action: @selector(resetState) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

vs

```
Qobject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &controller, SLOT(resetState()));
```